# Using an image editor to 'sign' scanned documents

Tags: document-scanning, graphics-editing

I often get emailed documents, which I have to print, initial and sign, scan, and email back.  I would much rather just scan a copy of my signature (or crop one out of a signed, scanned document n archive), and keep that on hand.  When I need to sign a document, I can just edit the document image and impose my initials and signature where required.

My vector and bitmap editors of choice are Expression Design 4 and Paint.NET on Windows 7.  How would I go about adding my signature image to scanned documents, normally in *.tiff format, using these either or both of these editors?

This scenario still presents issues if I'm sent a document in a format like PDF, as I can't edit PDF in a bitmap editor.  This brings me to my related question, [Convert PDF and Word documents to TIFF images.](https://superuser.com/questions/216651/convert-pdf-and-word-documents-to-tiff-images)

Comment: You didn't say, but I take it neither of those editors support TIFF?

Answer (score 2):

Using [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org) you can convert any PDF to an image file and edit it as you would any other bitmap. Just add your signature as a layer, set the blend to "multiply" or "darken" and you are done.

Comment: I'm using Paint.NET, so I'll have to find an external or plugin conversion, but the rest of your answer looks solid, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To sign PDFs with a scan of my signature I use the stamp function in [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer). There is a free version of this software that includes this function.